# How to set owner of directory in Docker

Tags: docker, permissions, docker-volume, chown

I'm trying to create a directory owned by a specific user in Docker. I'm using this Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:14.4.0-alpine

COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install .
ENV PATH=/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

RUN addgroup -S gofit && adduser -S gofit -G gofit
RUN mkdir /test && chown -R gofit:gofit /test && chmod 777 /test
USER gofit
WORKDIR /test
# if you delete this it's does not work either
VOLUME /test

CMD [ "npm", "test" ]
```

If I try to run the container with this command:

```
docker run -v `pwd`:/test -t gofit
```

I get the following error:

```
➜  gofit git:(master) ✗ docker run -v `pwd`:/test -it gofit 

> goFit@1.0.0 test /test
> ava


  ✖ Internal error
  Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/test/node_modules/.cache/ava'
  Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/test/node_modules/.cache/ava'
      at Object.mkdirSync (fs.js:940:3)
      at Api._createCacheDir (/node_modules/ava/lib/api.js:274:6)
      at Api.run (/node_modules/ava/lib/api.js:117:20)
      at Object.exports.run (/node_modules/ava/lib/cli.js:474:31)
      at Object.<anonymous> (/node_modules/ava/cli.js:10:23)
      at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1200:30)
      at Object.Module._extensions..js(internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1220:10)
      at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1049:32)
      at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:937:14)
      at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
  ─

npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
```

But that's because the owner of `/test` is changed when whe volume is mounted. If I run

```
docker run -v `pwd`:/test -t gofit ls -la
```

I get:

```
total 188
drwxrwxr-x    7 node     node          4096 Oct 26 12:56 .
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          4096 Oct 26 13:22 ..
drwxrwxr-x    8 node     node          4096 Oct 26 12:56 .git
drwxrwxr-x    3 node     node          4096 Oct 26 12:56 .github
-rw-rw-r--    1 node     node          1817 Oct 26 12:56 .gitignore
-rw-rw-r--    1 node     node           278 Oct 26 13:17 Dockerfile
-rw-rw-r--    1 node     node         35149 Oct 26 12:56 LICENSE
-rw-rw-r--    1 node     node          2244 Oct 26 12:56 README.md
drwxrwxr-x    3 node     node          4096 Oct 26 12:56 docs
-rw-rw-r--    1 node     node            26 Oct 26 12:56 index.js
-rw-rw-r--    1 node     node           258 Oct 26 12:56 iv.yaml
-rw-rw-r--    1 node     node         89131 Oct 26 12:56 package-lock.json
-rw-rw-r--    1 node     node           796 Oct 26 12:56 package.json
drwxrwxr-x    3 node     node          4096 Oct 26 12:56 src
drwxrwxr-x    2 node     node          4096 Oct 26 12:56 tests
-rw-rw-r--    1 node     node         10030 Oct 26 12:56 words.dic
```

But if I run it without mounting the volume, I get the expected owner:

```
drwxrwxrwx    2 gofit    gofit         4096 Oct 26 13:16 .
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          4096 Oct 26 13:23 ..
```

Anyone knows what's going on? How can I set the permissions to let the user `gofit` run the tests? Or should I use `node` user?

Comment: See the id of the gofit user using `id gofit` from within the container. May be you can give permission for the volume mapped files to a user in host machine with same id.
You can also try to edit the gofit user using `usermod` and give it the node user's id, but I am not sure if that will work.

Comment: Alpine does not let you create users with the same UUID.